“Undefined” error trying to save WooCommerce Payment Credentials with MercadoPago Integration on the SiteBoss Platform
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to save WooCommerce payment credentials with MercadoPago integration on the SiteBoss platform. Upon entering the credentials and clicking on "Save and Continue," I'm consistently presented with an "Undefined" error message.
I've tried repeating the procedure multiple times, reloading both the platform page and the MercadoPago page. Additionally, I created test credentials in my own MercadoPago account to verify that the issue isn't related to the client's account.
Has anyone else experienced this error before, and if so, what steps did you take to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Hi, consider providing an MCVE to get more attention and quicker response from the experts.
